# R: Walk up a directory tree up to a particular directory

Tags: r, directory, path, filepath

### Question

Let's say my current file path obtained using `basename` is: `a/b/c/d/e/f`. How do I walk up to a particular directory, say `c`?

### Nuances

I am trying to get a generalized solution to reach directory `c`. One way is to hard code and go few steps up by hard coding. I want to avoid it because I am working on a collaborative project and the local paths might differ when project files are handled by team members on different systems.

### Existing questions

[How to walk up a tree in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797089/how-to-walk-up-a-tree-in-r) : This question is more than 10 years old and is related with the webpages

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37381191/2761575: This is a hard-coded solution. Might not be suitable for collaborative projects.

### Answer in an existing question

[In R, how to find a file located in any parent directory upper than working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67791408/in-r-how-to-find-a-file-located-in-any-parent-directory-upper-than-working-dire) : This question focusses on finding the files, but the answers can be used to locate directory as well.

Answer pasted below for only convenience, credits to the original author.

```
find_up <- function(file, path=getwd()){
  d <- dirname(path)
  if(file.exists(here <- file.path(path, file))) here
  else  if(grepl('/', sub('/+$', '', d)))  find_up(file, d)
  else message('file does not exist')
}
```

Thank you community members for support.

Comment: `setwd('..')` will take you up to the parent of the current directory.  This answer is related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37381191/2761575

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer. However, I am looking for a more generalized solution.  I have edited the question to add relevant information.

Comment: How exactly do you want to "walk up"? Are you just trying to return the partial path? Or are you actually trying to change the working directory? Are you trying to find a folder name with an exact string match? What should happen if the folder doesn't exist? Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67791408/in-r-how-to-find-a-file-located-in-any-parent-directory-upper-than-working-dire